# Reading a file uploaded via CGI in Python

Tags: python, upload, cgi

I am having trouble analyzing a file that is uploaded to my server.  Ideally, what would happen is that the user would upload a .csv and I would run some numeric integration (hence the `import numpy as np`) from data in the file and return the result.  To test the cgi part before I did any analysis, I made the python script below.  My problem is that message always appears blank, so I get a blank html page displayed in browser at the end.

Clearly I am not reading the file correctly (which means I can not analyze it), but I have n o idea what I am doing wrong.  My own searches indicate that what I have below should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#---------------------------------------------
#=============================================
#---------------------------------------------
#imports

#import csv
#import time as tm
#import numpy as np
#import os
import cgi, cgitb

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

#The variables
#httpopen=""
#httpclose=""
message="meow"

#get the fileitem
fileitem=form['userfile']
if fileitem.file:
    #yay...we got a file
    message=fileitem.file.readline()


print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>
""" % (message,)
```

And here is the html form that gives the upload:

```
<html>
<body>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                     action="capacity_rewrite.py" method="post">
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="userfile" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only reading one line from the uploaded file. Perhaps that first line is a blank line? Try `fileitem.file.read()` instead, which will read the entire file into a string. Don't do that for large files as you may run out of memory, but it should help in understanding your test.

Comment: That was it.  I feel like a complete idiot.  The file was not supposed to have a blank line, so I just assumed that it was in the format I expected.  Thanks.